# How do you make this design in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to know how to make this design in flutter - I know there is a library for it or a built in function but I forgot what it is called. I included an image (just the white and purple part). Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can set it with stack widget also  but if you go through below you can manage ‘hope you are having a nice day’ dynamically in future also

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClassHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClassHome({super.key});

  @override
  State<ClassHome> createState() => _ClassHomeState();
}

class _ClassHomeState extends State<ClassHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      body: Column(
        children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                            Text("Hey, Danial"),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                              child: Text("Hope you are having a nice day!"),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.notifications_none_rounded)
                  ],
                ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                )
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Find your related job!"),

                  //Other child widgets...
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Figured it out just now but did a similar solution - thought you could do it with a library but guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 80,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15,vertical: 5),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("Hey, Danial"),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Text("Hope you are having a nice day!"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.notifications_none_rounded, color: Colors.white)
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                  )),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Find your related job!"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Result: [image]